# How to properly execute `gif-screencast-stop` before `save-buffers-kill-emacs`?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu.

I have installed `gif-screencast` and have gotten it to start recording whenever i start Emacs by adding

```
(gif-screencast)
```

to my `init.el`. So far, so good. The problem is saving the recording when killing Emacs. I have tried to add both

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'gif-screencast-stop)
```

and

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'gif-screencast-stop)
```

to my `init.el`, but none of them manage to stop the recording and save it *before* Emacs asks me whether I want to kill running processes. When I answer 'yes', it will, of course, kill the `gif-screencast` process before ending it properly.

My current solution, arrived at by trial and error, is to add

```
(advice-add 'save-buffers-kill-emacs :before #'gif-screencast-stop)
```

to `init.el`. This works when killing Emacs by using the GUI menu, but not when using `C-x C-c` from within Emacs. When I try the latter, i get `Wrong number of arguments: (0.0), 1`. When I do the former, it correctly saves the `gif-screencast` recording before giving me the `Save file ...?` prompt and then killing Emacs.

Edit: it gives me 2 prompts:
First, it gives me `Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway?`, then it gives me `Save file ...?`. The first one of these is the one that has to wait until after `gif-screencast` has properly finished.

My syntax is wrong somehow, but I'm not experienced enough with `elisp` to figure it out.

How do I make this execute correctly also when killing Emacs with `C-x C-c`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

I think your advice function should have the same signature as `save-buffer-kill-emacs`, i.e. it should take an optional argument (which it can go ahead and ignore of course):

```el
(defun my/gif-screencast-shutdown (&optional arg)
   (gif-screencast-stop))

(advice-add 'save-buffers-kill-emacs :before #'my/gif-screencast-shutdown)
```

That should take care of the `Wrong number of arguments` message (although I don't understand why/how it works from the GUI and not when called with `C-x C-c`).

This is all untested and may be completely wrong, but try it and see.

Comment: Thanks, @NickD! This does save the gif, and gives me the `Active processes exist; kill them and exit anyway?` prompt afterwards.

However, it stumbles on the `Do you want to save ...` prompt. This never shows, and Emacs never quits.

I tried using `C-u C-x C-c` instead of just `C-x C-c` in order to silently save all buffers, and then it works just fine, because I never encounter the `Do you want to save ...` prompt.

Edit: I realize i was unclear on the two different prompts in my original question. I will update and clarify.